# error in sortwith of scala

Tags: scala, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list and here is my code:

```
lab.toList.sortWith( days(_) < days(_)).foreach(labEntry => {
....
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Type mismatch, expected: (ODocument, ODocument) => Boolean, actual: (ODocument, ODocument) => Any
```

Comment: What's the definition of `days`?

Comment: `days` is a list and also one field in a ODocument. I want to sort elements of `lab` based on the elements in `days` (`days` are all integer values and somehow represent date)

Comment: is lab also a list of integers? otherwise if what you want to do is sort a list of items, and days is a sorting of the index of lab, then you may try lab.zipWithIndex.sortWith((x,y) => days(x._2) > days(y._2)).map(x => x._1)

Comment: You're right. lab is also a list of integers.

Comment: Don't you want _.days then not days(_)?

Comment: Your error message is saying that `days` is a list of `ODocument`, not integers, and the `<` method is returning `Any`